# How to compare two rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a truck that make deliveries, at every stop the driver records the name of the street. I would like to compare departure and destination to make sure  the driver they match:

```
Departures   | Destination
-------------+--------------
Duck Street  | Alley street.
Alley street | Simpson street.
```

I just want to make sure that the old destination from row 1 and new departure from row2 always match. I have tried   the update trigger in MySQL but I don't understand the syntax  please help

Comment: Why not use a join?

Comment: Are `departure - destination` records go in strict ordered sequence or there are any other trucks registered?

Comment: I'm not sure i understand what you mean  Join,its a two column table.

Comment: Just one truck , the rows  ordered  normally one after another

Comment: Self Join but not really possible if you cannot guarantee the order do you have and id field?

Comment: Please provide the table structure you have, primary key, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Your table should have an incrementing `id` (or time indication) so that you can identify which is the last inserted street.

If your table looks like this:

```
create table itinerary (
    id               int         auto_increment,
    departure_street varchar(100),
    arrival_street   varchar(100),
    primary key (id)
);
```

... then you could add this trigger:

```
create trigger tr_ins_itinerary before insert on itinerary for each row
    set new.departure_street = (
      select   arrival_street
      from     itinerary
      order by id desc
      limit    1);
```

See [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bc6dc/1).

You might have different drivers, and store the `driver_id` in that table. In that case you need a `where` clause in the trigger:

```
...where driver_id = new.driver_id...
```